# How to declare and define Poco Logger?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, poco-libraries

I use the excellent Poco framework for logging. Currently, I define the Logger and LogStream like this in my header files:

```
#Foo.h

....

class Foo
{
    private:
        Poco::Logger &logger = Poco::Logger::get("Foo");
        Poco::LogStream logStream{ logger };

};
```

This has served quite well until I started using [boost::di](https://boost-experimental.github.io/di/). When I use boost injector to create an object for Foo like this,

```
injector.create<Foo>();
```

I get a compiler error saying,

> attempting to reference a deleted function

However, if I remove the LogStream definition, I'm not getting the compiler error. Is it possible to declare LogStream in the header without defining it? I'm quite new to C++ and I'd be glad if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here and how to do it right. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably your `Foo` instances are copied, but base class of `Poco::LogStream` is `std::ostream` which is non-copyable, so your `Foo` instances cannot be copied. To avoid this problem you could make `logStream` be some kind of smart pointer, `std::shared_ptr` or `Poco::SharedPtr`.

Comment: Thanks @rafix07 for taking your time to write that out. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: You don't need to store `Poco::Logger &logger` as data member of this class (references cannot be copied so default copy assignment operator cannot be generated). You could do `Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::LogStream> logStream{new Poco::LogStream(Poco::Logger::get("Foo"))};`. Call `Logger::get` and pass returned value into Poco::LogStream ctor.

Comment: Hi @rafix07, the memory won't be managed automatically while using "new", will it be? Do we need to use "delete" in the dtor?

Comment: Hi, `SharedPtr` controls the lifetime of `LogStream`, you don't do it manually.

Comment: Hi @rafix07, thank you very much for your suggestions. I tried it and it worked. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instances of `Foo` cannot be copied due to two reasons:

1) `logger` is reference, reference must be initialized when `Foo` is created, so the only way
to do this is to use constructors. 
Compiler cannot generate copy assignment operation. So `Foo f1,f2; f1 = f2;` cannot work.

2) Base class of `LogStream` is `std::ostream` which has disabled copy operations.

Solution: 
remove `logger` as data member, it is superfluous here,
because we can call `Poco::Logger` while `LogStream` is initialized.

```
class Foo {
    //...
    Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::LogStream> logStream{
        new Poco::LogStream(Poco::Logger::get("Foo"))};
};
```

To make `Foo` be copyable you can use `Poco::SharedPtr`.

Comment: Will there be any impact if std:shared_ptr is used instead?

Comment: You can easily use `std::shared_ptr` here. There is no difference.

Comment: Thank you very much @rafix07. Works great.